# SQL query is not effected in VB6 Recordset

Tags: sql, vb6

I have this SQL query, it runs well in MSAccess VBA and creates a MSAccess query, but in VB6 it is not effected:

```
SELECT
    top 1000 NhapKHO.*
    ,NHANVIEN.NAME as N
    ,NHANVIEN.FNAME as FN
    ,NhaCC.MaNCC
    ,NhaCC.TenNCC
    ,DMKHO.MaKho
    ,DMKHO.TenKho
FROM
    DMKHO
RIGHT JOIN (NhaCC RIGHT JOIN (NHANVIEN RIGHT JOIN NhapKHO ON NHANVIEN.ID = NhapKHO.ID_NV) ON NhaCC.ID = NhapKHO.ID_NCC) ON DMKHO.ID = NhapKHO.ID_KHO
WHERE
    ( (MaNCC like '*ibo*')
or
    (TenNCC like '*ibo*') 
or 
    (NGUOIGIAO like '*ibo*') 
or 
    (fname like '*ibo*')
or
    (name like '*ibo*')
or
    (ngaynhap like '*ibo*')
or
    (nhapkho.ID like '*ibo*'))
order by
    NhapKHO.id desc
```

The result returns empty.

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: RIGHT JOIN (NhaCC RIGHT JOIN -- what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your LIKE is wrong: use % as wildchar, instead of *. To show it:

```
...
or
    (name like '%ibo%')
or
...
```

Comment: In MS Access an asterisk is also a valid character for zero or more characters. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221192%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, but read this, it explains more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690731/ms-access-query-why-does-like-behave-differently-when-being-called-from-vb6-app

Comment: Yes, I knew about that. My point was the difference between and asterisk and a percent sign could not be what is causing the OP's problem.

Comment: The 690731 article explains, that using the wrong wildchar character IS the problem.